# Calculate $H^{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{2} ; Z(T))$

Tags: homology-cohomology, group-extensions

I would like to find how many group extensions of $T$ by $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$, where $T$ is the tetrahedral group (in the sense of the definition in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension).

I was told that there exists two such group extensions and I am trying to use a fact that: If there is an extension of a group $A$ by $G$, then $H^{2}(G; Z(A))$ classifies the extesions of $A$ by $G$. Hence, I would like to prove that 
$H^{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{2} ; Z(T)) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2}$, but I am not getting any success. Does anyone have a hint?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the fact you state?

Comment: It is the proposition 4 at http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/notes/GroupExtensions.pdf

Comment: The definitions of extension of $T$ by $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in the Wikipedia article and the note you link to are not the same.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Sorry that I've deleted this question, and thanks that you tried to anwser it.

Comment: No worries. Sorry my answer isn't complete. Hopefully it gets you started though.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese sorry that I didnt answer earlier, but it helps a lot, gave me some others ideas to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the document you linked to in the comments does not use the same terminology regarding extensions as Wikipedia does. Suppose there are groups $A$, $E$ and $G$ which fit into the following short exact sequence

$$0 \to A \to E \to G \to 0.$$

Wikipedia calls $E$ an extension of $G$ by $A$, whereas in the linked document, the group $E$ is called an extension of $A$ by $G$. You are using the same terminology as Wikipedia, so the in the statement of Proposition $4$, we need to swap $A$ and $G$.

As $\operatorname{Out}(\mathbb{Z}_2) = 0$ and $Z(\mathbb{Z}_2) = \mathbb{Z}_2$, Proposition $4$ tells us that $H^2(T; \mathbb{Z}_2)$ classifies the extensions of $T$ by $\mathbb{Z}_2$. By the Universal Coefficient Theorem, we have

$$H^2(T; \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(H_2(T; \mathbb{Z}), \mathbb{Z}_2)\oplus\operatorname{Ext}(H_1(T; \mathbb{Z}), \mathbb{Z}_2).$$

As $H_1(T; \mathbb{Z}) \cong T^{\text{ab}} \cong A_4^{\text{ab}} \cong \mathbb{Z}_3$ and $\operatorname{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}_3, \mathbb{Z}_2) = 0$, we just need to determine $H_2(T; \mathbb{Z})$ which is called the *Schur multiplier* of $T$. I personally don't know how to compute this, but it has been computed to be $\mathbb{Z}_2$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_groups_of_the_alternating_and_symmetric_groups#Integral_homology) for example. Therefore $H^2(T; \mathbb{Z}_2) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$.

So there are only two extensions of $T$ by $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Namely

$$0 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to \mathbb{Z}_2\times T \to T \to 0$$

and

$$0 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 2T \to T \to 0$$

where $2T$ is the binary tetrahedral group.